CSS parent with 3d perspective but not text child


const wrapper = document.querySelector('.conveyor');
var rows;
const [rowLeft, rowTop, rowRight, rowBottom] = rows = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.row');

var config = {
    timing: 300, 
}

function clockwise(){
    let rights = [...rowTop.querySelectorAll('.row-item')];
    let tops = [...rowLeft.querySelectorAll('.row-item')];
    let lefts = [...rowBottom.querySelectorAll('.row-item')];
    let bottoms = [...rowRight.querySelectorAll('.row-item')];
    const row_items = [...rights, ...tops, ...lefts, ...bottoms];
    function reachPos(){
        let l1 = tops.shift();
        let t1 = rights.pop();
        let r1 = bottoms.pop();
        let b1 = lefts.shift();
        rights.unshift(l1);
        bottoms.unshift(t1);
        lefts.push(r1);
        tops.push(b1);
        rights.forEach(e=>rowTop.appendChild(e));
        tops.forEach(e=>rowLeft.appendChild(e));
        lefts.forEach(e=>rowBottom.appendChild(e));
        bottoms.forEach(e=>rowRight.appendChild(e));
        console.log(rowTop.isConnected);
    }
    wrapper.classList.add('clockwise');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        row_items.forEach(r=>r.remove());
        wrapper.classList.remove('clockwise');
        reachPos();
    }, config.timing);
}

window.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    clockwise();
});
:root{
    --total-w: 500px;
    --row-w: 100px;
    --item-w: 80px;
    --margin: 10px;
    --side-padding: 35px;
    --item-count: 4;
    --trans: calc(var(--item-w) + var(--side-padding) + var(--margin) * 2);
    --timing: 300ms;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.conveyor{
    position: relative;
    width: var(--total-w);
    height: var(--total-w);
    border: 1px solid;
    perspective: 800px;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(65deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, cadetblue, lightgreen);
}

.conveyor .center-text{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    /*transform-origin: center center;
    transform: rotateX(-65deg) rotateZ(-45deg);*/
}

.row-top,
.row-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    height: var(--row-w);
    width: calc(100% - var(--row-w));
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-top{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding-right: var(--side-padding);
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.row-bottom{
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-left: var(--side-padding);
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.row-left,
.row-right{
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% - var(--row-w));
    width: var(--row-w);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-left{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: var(--side-padding);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.row-right{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: var(--side-padding);
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.row-item{
    width: var(--item-w);
    height: var(--item-w);
    background-color: wheat;
    margin: var(--margin);
    transform-style: flat;
    position: relative;
}

.conveyor .row .row-item .row-text{
    transform-style: flat;
    -webkit-transform-style: flat;
}

@keyframes cw-right{
    100%{
        transform: translateX(var(--trans));
    }
}

@keyframes cw-bottom{
    100%{
        transform: translateY(var(--trans));
    }
}

@keyframes cw-left{
    100%{
        transform: translateX(calc(0px - var(--trans)));
    }
}

@keyframes cw-top{
    100%{
        transform: translateY(calc(0px - var(--trans)));
    }
}

.conveyor.clockwise .row-top .row-item{
    animation: cw-right var(--timing) ease-out;
}
.conveyor.clockwise .row-right .row-item{
    animation: cw-bottom var(--timing) ease-out;
}
.conveyor.clockwise .row-bottom .row-item{
    animation: cw-left var(--timing) ease-out;
}
.conveyor.clockwise .row-left .row-item{
    animation: cw-top var(--timing) ease-out;
}
<div class="conveyor">
    <div class="row row-left">
        <div class="row-item">
            <div class="row-text">1 one</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-item">2 two</div>
        <div class="row-item">3 three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-top">
        <div class="row-item">12 twelve</div>
        <div class="row-item">11 eleven</div>
        <div class="row-item">10 ten</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-right">
        <div class="row-item">9 nine</div>
        <div class="row-item">8 eight</div>
        <div class="row-item">7 seven</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-bottom">
        <div class="row-item">4 four</div>
        <div class="row-item">5 five</div>
        <div class="row-item">6 six</div>
    </div>

    <div class="center-text">
        CENTER
    </div>
</div>



trying to dev a 3d conveyor belt in css, the logic is pretty simple:

parent set a 3d pespective transformation
four rows, each only occpy one cornor
js click to rearrange positions
toggle css .clockwise to translate item

but there is a BIG issue I CANNOT SOLVE, text at center and texts on each item, should not display that way as 3d, instead, I seek for a way to display the text normally facing the audience.
thinking about this all day, have not come up with an elegant approach, will be more than glad if u can give me a hand.

What do you mean by facing the audience? In which direction you want text?

No, you can not rotate an element, and have that not affect its descendants at the same time. But you could rotate the descendants "back", to try and reverse the effect of the rotation of the ancestor - something like transform: rotateX(5deg) rotateZ(-45deg); applied to the .row-item elements, come close to what you want? (That works only for the "static" display, not while you animate the elements. How to do the latter correctly, might need some more figuring out.)

I want the belts to maintain 3d transformation, meanwhile the text node on each square to discard the transformation on its parents, which locate where it is located now and keep moving with the belt (move with parent, like a child does, but is not influenced by the parent’s transformation just like @CBroe interprets)

I understand it is most likely impossible, but since it’s text node, I thought there may be some tricky special way (which is out of my knowledge), that can allow me to display text discarding all parent’s transformation, and let text appear as it appears in default.
